relative adverbial usage of 'that' when the antecedent is a/the (adjective) place


I am so glad that they have a safe place that they protect their family.




I am so glad that they have the safe place that they protect their family.




I am so glad that they have a place that they protect their family.




I am so glad that they have the place that they protect their family.


I wonder if the relativizer 'that' after 'place' is grammartical or idiomatic.

I don't think the second that is syntactically valid here. Using where is better, but I'm not convinced even that makes a strictly valid utterance with the meaning you intend. What you're literally saying is that the subject is able to do his "protecting" in that place - but what you mean is [that] his family is protected by virtue of being in that place (perhaps only because he has provided them with such a place). Whatever - it's not good to be analyzing the relativizer 'that' after 'place' in such a syntactically / stylistically weak example utterance.

None of these is grammatical or idiomatic.

Maybe consider I'm lucky [that] I have a job [that] I like. Which thanks to the recursive nature of the syntax could in principle be extended to I'm lucky [that] I have a job [that] I like that pays well. But I can't explain why that final that is obligatory, where the others are optional.

hi, @FumbleFingers, in
'I'm lucky [that] I have a job [that] I like that pays well',
the first that is a marker for the declarative content clause and is optional. The second that, the relativiser for the first relative clause, is the object of the relative  clause and is hence optional.  The third that, the relativiser for the last relative clause, is the subject of the relative clause and is hence required.

@Xanne Is there any reason you say none of these is grammatical or idiomatic?


I am so glad that they have a safe place that they protect their family.

This is incorrect, because the second emphasised "that" is not correctly linking the two clauses.
If the emphasis is on a location, then where is better:

I am so glad that they have a safe place where they can protect their family.

If the emphasis is on the fact that the house itself provides safety (It's got good alarms, well fenced), then you need to make sure the relative clause refers to the house, not the family. Something like this:

I am so glad [that] they have a place that provides safety and protection for their family.


(Without 'where') "I am so glad that they have a safe place they can protect their family." Is the sentence acceptable(grammatically or idiomatically)?

I think it depends what you are trying to say. Consider this sentence: I am so glad that they have a safe place so they can protect their family. This focusses less on the location of the safe house, and more on its purpose. The difference is subtle, but it is there. As it stands, the reader has to work harder to interpret your sentence.

Gomadeng, if I heard someone say that I would think they were a careless or uneducated  speaker and meant where they can.
